# Pluriel de mot scénario

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, orthographe, pluriel, italien

Je voudrais savoir : C'est quoi le pluriel de mot scénario

. scénarii

ou

. scénarios

J'ai trouvé que les deux mots sont utilisés, mais lequel est le meilleur?

Comment: Il n'y a pas de « meilleur ». Si tu donnes un contexte peut-être que quelqu'un pourra t'aider à choisir. M'enfin vu [les statistiques](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+sc%C3%A9narios%2Cdes+scenarii%2Cdes+sc%C3%A9narii&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20sc%C3%A9narios%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20scenarii%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20sc%C3%A9narii%3B%2Cc0), si tu ne veux pas attirer l'attention sur le mot lui-même, c'est pas dur de choisir.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment un mot latin, mais ça rentre dans la même catégorie et si tu ne précises pas de contexte c'est le même genre de question. Par ailleurs, demander quel est le meilleur, c'est subjectif et ça aurait été de toute façon clos avec pour motif « [primarily opinion-based](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) ».

Comment: lorsqu'on parle d'un scénario d'exécution , si on aura plus qu'un seul scénario , qu'est ce qu'on doit dire?

Comment: Pour un scénario de cinéma, l'usage a tendance à préférer *scenarii*. Autrement, *scénarios* est parfaitement correct.